# How do I kill a thread on wait?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public void stop(){
    setRun(false);
    inComingWorkThread.interrupt();
    outGoingWorkThread.interrupt();
}
```

I was trying to stop those thread using interrupt call. And I got an interrupt exception.

```
public class OutgoingListWorker implements Runnable{

@Override
public void run() {
     while(mRunning){
          WorkOrder workOrder = getWorkOrder();
          //do something
     }
}

public synchronized WorkOrder getWorkOrder(){
    while(mWorkOrderList.size() == 0){
        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    return mWorkOrderList.poll();
}

public synchronized void addWorkOrder(WorkOrder workOrder){
    this.notify();
    mWorkOrderList.add(workOrder);
}
```

The problem is getWokrOrder calls wait and if an interrupt happened this time then it won't kill the thread.. How do I kill the blocked thread safely? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you catch the `InterruptedException` and continue looping...

### Exception Handling

There are two ways you could deal with this:

Catch the `InterruptedException` outside of the loop and return `null`.

```
public synchronized WorkOrder getWorkOrder() {
    WorkOrder workOrder = null;

    try {
        while(mWorkOrderList.size() == 0) {
            this.wait();
        }

        mworkOrder = WorkOrderList.poll();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return workOrder;
}
```

Using this option, you would need to handle the case where `getWorkOrder()` returns `null` in your `run()` method:

```
if (workOrder != null) {
    //do something
}
```

Or secondly, you could just throw `InterruptedException` and force your `run()` method to do something about it.

```
public synchronized WorkOrder getWorkOrder() throws InterruptedException {
    while(mWorkOrderList.size() == 0){
        this.wait();
    }

    return WorkOrderList.poll();
}
```

### Interrupts

As a side note, there is no need to maintain a `mRunning` variable. That is exactly what interrupts do for you!

Instead of:

```
while(mRunning) {
    WorkOrder workOrder = getWorkOrder();
    //do something
}
```

Just write:

```
while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
    WorkOrder workOrder = getWorkOrder();
    //do something
}
```

And then you don't even need to call `setRun(false);` at all! Here is a good tutorial about interrupts: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Answer (score 1):

You could always add `mRunning` as a condition to the `wait()` loop in `getWorkOrder()`:

```
while(mWorkOrderList.size() == 0 && mRunning){
    try {
        this.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}

if (mWorkOrderList.size() > 0) {
    return mWorkOrderList.poll();
}
return null;
```

Now, when you interrupt the thread, the loop condition won't be true and you'll drop out of the `wait()` loop. You also need to make sure that there's actually an order to return (shown above), and you'll have to add a null check in the `run()` loop as well (not shown.)